# Is google map being instantiated once every vue-router navigation?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

this question is coming from me getting a rather big $ bill surprise with the Javascript Google Maps API.

Essentially, I launched our Real Estate based web app, ran some ads, got some traffic, which resulted in a much larger bill than expected. One of the reasons the bill was higher than expected was due to the maps API was hit an obscene amount of times, especially compared to traffic.

I'm using Vue routers.

Now, I have a route called `/listings`, on said route there is a map, (using vue2-google-maps), as well as a list view.

Hypotheses, every time a user hits `/listings`, the components/page get's rendered and a dynamic map request is sent? Meaning a single user can easily send off 10, 20, 100+ Gmap API requests just by navigating to different listings, then navigating back to the map search. Can anyone confirm?

Now I am thinking about solutions already that would make use of a dialog, and `v-if` when a listing is selected it appears overtop, essentially never navigating away from the `/listings` page.

However, am I correct in my assumption? And if so, is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Essentially, nobody can answer this question without looking at the code. From what you describe, you're instantiating a map every time your're mounting the listings view. But you can find the answer yourself by simply looking at the "Network" tab in dev tools and see when a request to maps API is made.

Comment: Fair enough, and yes - it does appear it instantiates a new map every time it hits the route. 

Considering I'm paying for every new map generated, it's frustating

Comment: Have you tried to cache components using keep-alive? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

Used `<keep-alive>` around the `<router-view>` and worked!